# In SQLite3, how to select with match to any item of a list?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I use 'sqlite3' to access a database in a Python program. 
I have a list of keywords, for example,

```
fruit=['banana','apple','orange']   #the total number is 50.
```

If I have following table:

```
Col 1                       | Col 2
'this is a desk'            | something else
'banana is good for health' | something else
'bad apple'                 | something else
```

How can I select the rows where Col 1 contains any item from fruit, e.g. in this example, row 2 and 3 should be selected?

I am aware of the 'LIKE' command for one item, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Col 1 LIKE '%banana%'
```

But I don't know how to do it with a list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **OR** operator for selecting rows with different values.

```
SELECT "Col 1" 
FROM table 
WHERE 
"Col 1" LIKE '%banana%' OR 
"Col 1" LIKE '%apple%' OR 
"Col 1" LIKE '%orange%'
```

Comment: This list is very long, e.g. 50 items. Using OR would be quite troublesome,

Comment: Also you can use contains `WHERE CONTAINS("Col 1", '"*banana*" OR "*apple*" OR "*orange*"')`.

Comment: Or regex `WHERE "Col 1" REGEXP 'banana|apple|orange'`.